# An Unexpected Error while installing Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Windows boot manager is showing error while installing windows 7

> Windows has encountered a problem communicating with a device
>   connected to your computer If you continue to receive this error
>   message contact the hardware manufacturer
>
> Status:  0xc00000e9
>
> Info: An unexpected I/O error has occurred

All I can do is hit Enter or ESC and either key causes the computer to reboot, bringing me back to the same error screen. I have unplugged everything from the computer except the monitor, keyboard, and mouse. What can I do? Previously I used Ubuntu don't know why its showing error while installing. I have gone through several forums but the result is same. It is a Windows-7 64-bit machine.

Comment: What have you already tried to fix the problem?

Comment: Who approved the revisions without fixing the question itself to quote the error not part of the question?

Answer (score -1):

A little googling showed this thread (solved) with a very similar problem. http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/199929-status-0xc00000e9.html

Sounds like you have a little problem with the driver for your disk.

It also sounds a lot like a problem I experienced long time ago with XP and Vista installs as well. My method was to clean up the disk completely (use gparted or something removing everything from the disk).
If you have another disk lying around for testing, try to install on that to see if it actually is the disk that's giving you the problem or some other hardware issue.